# WPF has no entry point

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sharpdevelop, entry-point

I'm using `SharpDevelop` and had by my bad moved the `App.xaml` to an Subdirectory.

When i try to start/debug the Application, C# says, that my Application has no entry points or a static main method (CS5001).

An `Edit < Undo` or an movint to the default main folder will be not working.

Whats wrong?

**Edit**
On Project-Settings, no Classes/Methods are listened:
[image]

**App.xaml**

`<Application x:Class="SongManager.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Startup="Boot">
</Application>`

**App.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using SmuleTools;

namespace SongManager {
    public partial class App : Application {
        private Account user;

        public App() {

        }

        public Account getAccount() {
            return this.user;
        }

        [STAThread]
        private void Boot(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) {
            Login login = new Login();

            login.AuthSuccess((Object result) => {
                this.user       = (Account) result;
                Manager window  = new Manager(this);
                window.Show();
                login.Close();
            });

            login.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Restore from backup (Git) ?

Comment: For  a manual repair, create a new empty project and find the differences.

Comment: Is the App class listed in the "Startup object" ComboBox under Project->Properties? There you should be able to select the type that contains the Main method of the application

Comment: When i'm using Git, i had roll back, sure. But currently i'm using not Git on these project @bommelding

Comment: @mm8 no, on the left Dropdown i can select `Windows Application`, `Console Application`, `Library` or `.NET Module`, but on the right input/dropdown, no classes are listened; Here i have try to write it manually (with and without namespace)

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? Did you try to move the App.xaml file back to the root folder?

Comment: @mm8 see question-**tags** and **the question** on the first line - Here you see, i'm using `SharpDevelop`

Comment: I've found the correct solution (see my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Solution is a little bit tricky, but **easy**.

After moving the main `.xaml` file, the **Build action** will be lost - These are **not** in the Project/Compiler settings!

**Step-by-Step:**

1. ***(red mark)*** Click on your `.xaml` file (for sample, `App.xaml`)
2. ***(blue mark)*** Go to the **Properties** window (on the right side!)
3. ***(green mark)*** Change `Other > Build action` to `ApplicationDefinition`

**Screenshot**

[image]

That is it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `Main()` method to your `App` class:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    App application = new App();
    application.Run();
}
```

By default, there should be one generated when you build the application.